# Reading Excel file without hidden columns in Python using Pandas or other modules

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Can anyone tell me how to read the Excel file without hidden columns in Python with Pandas or any other modules?

When I try to read excel file using Pandas, for example:

```
file_np = pd.read_excel(f_name)
```

the dataframe file_np always contain all the column. From this dataframe, I do not know how to identify which column was hidden in the Excel file.
Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I don't think `pandas` does it out of the box.

**Input**

[image]

You will have to unfortunately do some redundant reading (twice). `openpyxl` does what you want -

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

loc = 'sample.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(loc)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

hidden_cols = []
for colLetter,colDimension in ws.column_dimensions.items():
    if colDimension.hidden == True:
        hidden_cols.append(colLetter)

df = pd.read_excel(loc)
unhidden = list( set(df.columns) - set(hidden_cols) )
df = df[unhidden]
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    C   A
0   1   7
1   9   7
2   5  10
3   7   7
4   4   8
5   4   6
6   9   9
7  10   3
8   1   2
```

**Explanation**

Reading the file first using `openpyxl` -

```
loc = 'C:/Users/FGB3140/Desktop/sample.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(loc)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
```

Searching for hidden property in cells (this is where the hidden columns are captured)

```
hidden_cols = []
for colLetter,colDimension in ws.column_dimensions.items():
    if colDimension.hidden == True:
        hidden_cols.append(colLetter)
```

Read the same file using pandas - `df = pd.read_excel(loc)`

Find the unhidden columns by subtracting the hidden ones from the rest -

```
unhidden = list( set(df.columns) - set(hidden_cols) )
```

Finally, filter out the unhidden columns -

```
df = df[unhidden]
```

**P.S**

I know I could have done `colDimension.hidden == False` or simple `if not colDimension.hidden` - The goal here is to capture the hidden columns and then do the filtering accordingly. Hope this helps!

Comment: This function from openpyxl is deprecated `get_sheet_by_name` and after run the code (which takes long) it keeps showing all the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd


def find_hidden_columns(xls_path, sheet):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(xls_path)
    ws = wb[sheet]

    hidden_cols = []
    for col in ws.iter_cols(min_row=1, max_col=ws.max_column, max_row=1):
        if ws.column_dimensions[col[0].column_letter].hidden:
            hidden_cols.append(col[0].col_idx - 1)
    return hidden_cols

 xls_path = "..."
 sheet_name = "..."

 df = pd.read_excel(xls_path, sheet_name=sheet_name, header=None)
 drop_columns = find_hidden_columns(xls_path, sheet_name)
 df = df.drop(columns=drop_columns)
```