# How to copy only visible cells?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to merge only visible cells in Excel, but I failed.

`openpyxl` may help me with `row_dimemsion[].hidden` but it didn't work.

Is there any other ways to show only visible cells?

I want only visible cells because sometimes they need to be filtered or hidden.

Please kindly advise me.

The links below don't work:

1. [Reading Excel file without hidden columns in Python using Pandas or other modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292496/reading-excel-file-without-hidden-columns-in-python-using-pandas-or-other-module)
2. [Finding hidden cells using openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257353/finding-hidden-cells-using-openpyxl)

```
import os
import glob
import xlwings as xw
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter


xw.App().visible = False
path = os.getcwd()
x=input('name：') + '.xlsx'
target_xls = os.path.join(path,x)
data = []
for file in glob.glob(path+'\*.*'):
    if file.endswith((".xls", ".xlsm", ".xlsx")):

        wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
        for sheet in wb.sheets():
            for rownum in range(sheet.nrows):
                data.append(sheet.row_values(rownum))
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(target_xls)
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        for i in range(len(data)):
            for j in range(len(data[i])):
                worksheet.write(i, j, data[i][j])
        workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

I hope it can show only visible cells when I filtered or hidden cells:

[image]

[image]

Comment: but how does it work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46002159/how-to-import-filtered-excel-table-into-python

Comment: ***but how does it work?***: The linked answer claims it works using `.hidden`. So why don't you use this approach?