# How to Un-Hide Rows and Columns in Excel files and Concatenate them in Pandas Data Frame?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, hidden-files

I have a lot of Excel files(10,000) with hidden columns and rows and I want to put them in one big Data Frame but the problem is in Data Frame I can not see those hidden columns and rows. I tried

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('yourfile.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('YourSheetName')
for row in ws.rows:
  if not row.value:
    ws.row_dimensions[row.rows].hidden = False
```

This gives an error and I can not find any sol with xlsxwriter as well.

I am looking for something like a simple for loop or something that can iterate and unhide the rows and columns and create a Data Frame. Any help would be much appreciated.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1W1qlveTPWdp9pyrdu3LLksibM5713xKc?usp=sharing

Files are in this folder.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292496/reading-excel-file-without-hidden-columns-in-python-using-pandas-or-other-module

Comment: _This gives an error_ Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Comment: I can't figure it out that's why I posted it here bro. I can't find anything to unhide the rows of multiple files. @AMC

Comment: @JohnT I checked this example but it does not work in this case with multiple files.

Comment: @Charles I never tried with multiple files. Any workaround I can think of wouldn't work well for 10,000 files. So hopefully someone with more knowledge will help

Comment: @BSL-5 do you have any idea?